# iPhone GPS navigation won't quit

Tags: ios, iphone, gps, xcode5

I have an iPhone application with a Navigation button on one of my Views. When the user clicks this button, it uses the phones CLLocationManager to open the iPhones GPS app. It then gets the users current location and shows navigation to a pre-defined set point.

All is OK here, but when I exit out of the GPS navigation (by clicking the phones Home button) and go back to the app, the app displays the view with the Navigate button on it for a second or 2, then fires up the GPS navigation again without me clicking on any buttons. I am also unable to click any buttons here like the back button in my top navigation bar.

Can anyone tell me why this is happening and how I can stop it? Here is my code for the GPS navigation.

In my viewDidLoad I have created the Navigation button programatically

```
UIButton *mapButton = [[UIButton alloc] init];
mapButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
mapButton.tag = 1;
mapButton.frame = CGRectMake(20, 430, 280.f, 40.f);
UIImage *mapButtonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"gettingHereMapButton.png"];
[mapButton setBackgroundImage:mapButtonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.view addSubview:mapButton];
[mapButton addTarget:self action:@selector(mapButtonClicked) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Which then goes to

```
- (void) mapButtonClicked
{
    self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
    locationManager.delegate = self;
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}

- (void) locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    UIAlertView *alert =
    [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Alert"
                           message:@"An error has occured. Please try again later."
                          delegate:self
                 cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                 otherButtonTitles:@"OK",
                 nil]; 
    [alert show];
}

- (void) locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
{
    CLLocation *newLocation = [locations lastObject];
    CLLocation *oldLocation;

    NSString *destAddress = @"52.269444, -9.708674";
    NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"http://maps.apple.com/maps?saddr=%f%f&daddr=%@",
                 newLocation.coordinate.latitude,
                 newLocation.coordinate.longitude,
                 [destAddress stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
}
```

What do I need to add to this view from stopping this from happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that when you do `[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];`, the locationManager calls `didUpdateLocations` multiple times.

To fix it, in

```
- (void) locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
```

Add this line:

```
[manager stopUpdatingLocation];
```

just above:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
```

Answer (score 0):

Even if you call `stopUpdatingLocation` location manger will not stop `didupdateLocations` immediately. It will call multiple time may be 2, 3, 4, or more time.

Better you can take one `BOOL` and check once your location has been updated set it to `YES` and call `stopUpdatingLocaiton`. So while `didUpdateLocations` call again check with your `BOOL`. And decide whether need to perform operation or not.

Note: Location Manager most of the time not will deliver exact location in one time. You have to be careful while deal with `CLLocationMananger`.

Before using CoreLocation Please read following links:

http://www.perspecdev.com/blog/2012/02/22/using-corelocation-on-ios-to-track-a-users-distance-and-speed/

http://www.peachpit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1830485&seqNum=2